# iOS Simulator makes headphones enter call mode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

Every time I open iOS Simulator my headphones enter call mode. Why MacOS thinks an open Simulator is like a running call?

Headphones are connected wirelessly (Beoplay H9i).

Comment: What devices have you selected in the simulator under Hardware->Audio input and Audio Output?

Answer (score 1):

Under Hardware, Audio Input select a different input device (such as built-in microphone).